# Wrong version after compilation and installation of qpdf

Tags: software-installation, make

I tried to install qpdf 5.1.3; the default one is 5.1.1 (I have Ubuntu 14.04).

After compiling it from [the sourceforge download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/files/qpdf/5.1.3/), version 5.1.1 is installed. The output of `/usr/local/bin/qpdf --version` is:

```
qpdf version 5.1.1  
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Jay Berkenbilt  
This software may be distributed under the terms of version 2 of the
Artistic License which may be found in the source distribution. It is
provided "as is" without express or implied warranty.
```

The output of `apt-cache policy qpdf`

```
qpdf:
Installed: 5.1.3-1
Candidate: 5.1.3-1
Version table:
*** 5.1.3-1 0
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
5.1.1-1 0
500 fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

It's confusing, and if I run

`find . -type f -name 'qpdf' -exec {} --version \;`

in the source folder I get

```
qpdf version 5.1.1  
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Jay Berkenbilt  
This software may be distributed under the terms of version 2 of the
Artistic License which may be found in the source distribution. It is
provided "as is" without express or implied warranty.  
qpdf version 5.1.3  
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Jay Berkenbilt  
This software may be distributed under the terms of version 2 of the
Artistic License which may be found in the source distribution. It is
provided "as is" without express or implied warranty.
```

so there seems to be two versions compiled.

What's wrong here?

Comment: What you are probably seeing with your `find` command is the difference between the actual binary (which goes in `qpdf/build/.libs`) and a libtool-generated wrapper script `qpdf/build/qpdf`. I don't know why the version string returned by the actual binary is apparently wrong OR how the libtool script returns a different one - sorry. BTW did you use `checkinstall`? If so you should probably add that info to your Q.